# Why not put an air compressor on an exhaust to store co2?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

For short-distance drives in a car, why not put an air compressor to store the co2 and dispose of later?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a ['Novel Idea' question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/311/1832). Such questions tend to become moving targets and lead to discussions, neither of which are a good fit for our format. See if you can [edit] your question to make it specific and answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside

- the added energy requirements to compress the CO2
- complexity technologies on the car you need to separate CO2 and store it (assuming its in a tank in gas form)

to my mind one important reason not to would be the following:

Burning one lit of gasoline, produces about 2.3 kg of CO2 (this is about 22.72 moles), which in Standard atmosphere conditions  (STP) this has the volume of 22.72 mol *22.4 L/mol= 545 lt (approximately 0.545 $m^3$).

Assuming a tank of gasoline of about  50 lit, that mean that you would produce about
115 kg or 25 $m^3$ in STP of of CO2.

If you wanted to store that much CO2 in bottle which is let's assume 250 lit, you'd have to find an air compressor of about 100 atm.

For comparison purposes

- the Toyota Camry trunk volume is 424 L.

[image]

- a usual pressure rating for medical oxygen cylinders is 130 atm.

[image]

**You would be driving around with the half a trunk occupied with a tank at a pressure of 100 atm**.

Comment: Did you ignore the fact air is 80% nitrogen? All that nitrogen is also in the engine exhaust. So is your volume estimate 5 times too low? (Or think of it another way: a 1-liter engine will be pumping say 1000 liters of air through the cylinders every minute...)

Comment: @alephzero I was hinting at that in the intro, "*complexity technologies on the car you need to **separate CO2** and store it (assuming its in a tank in gas form)*". Also your point about 1000 lt per minute is also a very valid, which I hadn't thought about.

Comment: @alephzero another thing is the elevated temperature o the exhaust fumes. You need to cool it down before you are able to store it.

Comment: Sorry, I dived into the numbers without reading the intro (since the concept is obviously fatally flawed in any case...) But don't try to scale this up to a jet-engine sized CO2 capture scheme, where the mass flow at maximum thrust is of the order of 1 tonne of air *per second* :)

Comment: How does a heat engine work? It adds heat at the high pressure side and then expands it. If the tank of CO2 is at a higher pressure, you don't have an engine anymore.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, they have been very helpful!